# How do you calculate a reasonable transaction fee?

Tags: transaction-fees, confirmations, blockspace-market

These days transactions are taking a very long time to confirm. Higher transaction fees could be a possible solution. I want to know how to calculate a reasonable transaction fee, which is not so expensive and results in less time until confirmation (within 10-15min). Could you advice me on how to implement it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See https://bitcoinfees.21.co/ for mempool size and tx fee. This will suggest fee in satoshi/byte depending on current network conditions.

If you are looking to exact fee in BTC for spending from wallet, you can try  https://github.com/shivaenigma/btxfees.

Comment: I was quite surprised at the size of fees - the 5000-10000 satoshi fees per transaction (2-5 cents?) are larger than participants/banks would pay for an international wire transfer in e.g. EU SEPA CT system.